# Why I cannot set background image in Angular 13?

Tags: html, css, angular, image

Following another stackoverflow answer, I tried following:

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url(https://picsum.photos/200)'"></div>
```

This does have no effect and no picture is shown. If I use the `<img>` tag instead and set the same url, it works. But I need it as a div background.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to set the image background of the div correctly?

Comment: You should work with css or scss. Also are you checking if there is CORS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stands in your div definition. A div element have nothing inside so his height/width is 0. Try to something like:

your.component.html:

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

your.component.css:

```
.image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200');
}
```

An example in stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bmrp6j